# Java - methods bind at run time

Tags: java, inheritance, methods, overriding

```
public class Any {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A ab = new **B**();
        System.out.println(ab.calc(2.0, 3.1));
    }
}

class A {
    public int calc(int a, int b) {
        return a+b;
    }
}

class B extends A {
    public double calc(double a, double b) {
        return a+b;
    }
}
```

Can someone please help me understand why does line 4 gives error:
"The method calc(int, int) in the type A is not applicable for the arguments (double, double)"

I understand Methods are bound at runtime; which method to execute depends on the type of object on which it's called. Method calc calls in class **B**. Why is compiler looking for method in class A.

Many thanks.

Comment: Because you defined the variable `ab` to be of type `A`. The compiler cannot prove that `ab` is *actually* a `B`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compiler is looking in class A because ab is of type

You need to understand the difference between compile-time polymorphism and runtime polymorphism.

Method overloading is compile time polymorphism and compiler always check for reference. Since ab is of reference(type) A, compiler will check for matching method in class A. In this case, it will not find a matching method which takes double as argument. Hence it throws an error.

Comment: Thanks. When I posted, I treated calc as overriden methods, they are not overriden methods as arguments are different.  They are kind of overloaded methods, though they are not in same class. Object ab doesn't have access to methods in class B, hence compiler gives  error.

Answer (score 0):

You can have runtime polymorphism in Java when you suddenly load a subclass of A by name that was written by someone else and which was never seen during your compilation. Because this can happen, HotSpot may not choose to inline code or perform other aggressive optimizations that would have to be undone in the event of a class loading dynamically. Believe it or not, HotSpot can still optimize and inline hot methods like this. It slams on the brakes and undoes the optimizations when a subclass is dynamically loaded! It might even re-inline the code later. Quite a trick. If you want your code to run faster, give HotSpot more chance to optimize by keeping members as private and final as possible. It’s good for your design anyway. For example, making class B final is a promise that no class can further specialize the calc method. Then if you are working with a B, hotspot can inline the code for that method if it’s in a loop and it can be sure this is safe and efficient.